# How to "split" in J2ME a String data containing new line characters?

Tags: java, java-me

I want to call a `PHP` `webservice` from my `J2ME` program. Here is the `PHP` `function` called :

```
...
$req="SELECT DISTINCT a.adc_id FROM adc a INNER JOIN utilisateur u ON a.adc_id=u.adc_id INNER JOIN transfert t ON u.user_code = t.user_code
WHERE t.user_code ='". $user_code ."' AND t.date_transfert='".$datejour."'";
$query=mysql_query($req) ;
while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $chaine .=$ligne['adc_id'].';';
    $chaine .= "\r\n" ;
}
return $chaine;
```

As you see there is the "`\r\n`" `new-line` character returned by the `webservice` among the column data. For example the returned String is :

```
12011;Michael;12/12/2012;
13455;Sue;14/05/2011;
```

So how to "split" this String data in `J2ME` so that I will get an array `String[]` containing the values :
`12011;Michael;12/12/2012;` and `13455;Sue;14/05/2011;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will either have to write your own tokenizer or use one of the many available on the net.

One example could be [this one from nokia's page](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/StringTokenizer_for_Java_ME)

Usage example:

```
Tokenizer t = new Tokenizer(yourString, "\r\n");
while (t.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = t.nextToken();
    //do something with token

}
```